# Getting the smallest element using std::min_element in vector of maps c++ via based-range loop

Tags: c++, min, stdvector, stdmap, std-pair

I'm trying to get min value using std::min_element in a function.

```
std::vector<std::map<int, double>> vectorMap;
std::map<int, double> data;


bool compare(std::pair<int, double> i, std::pair<int, double> j) {
  return i.second < j.second;
}

double findMin(std::vector<std::map<int, double>> const &vectorMap){
    for (auto const &vec : vectorMap){
        for (auto const &mymap : vec){
            std::pair<int, double> min = (*std::min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), compare));
        }
    }
    return static_cast<double>(min.second);
}
```

While compiling I'm getting these errors:

```
main.cpp:59:67: error: no member named 'begin' in 'std::pair<const int, double>'
            std::pair<int, double> min = (*std::min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), compare));
                                                            ~~~~~ ^

main.cpp:59:82: error: no member named 'end' in 'std::pair<const int, double>'
            std::pair<int, double> min = (*std::min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), compare));
                                                            ~~~~~ ^

main.cpp:62:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'min'
    return static_cast<double>(min.second);
```

But when using the std::min_element in the main function it works fine.

```
std::vector<std::map<int, double>> vectorMap;
std::map<int, double> data;

...
...

std::pair<int, double> min = (*std::min_element(data.begin(), data.end(), compare));
    std::cout << "min value is " << min.second << std::endl; //works well
```

[whole code](https://pastebin.com/Ui81rcgq)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: you only need one for loop not two

Comment: Don't use so many `auto`, you seem confused about the type of the variables, spelling them out would help you notice the issue.

Comment: There are many maps in the vector. You are trying to find many minimal elements (one per each vector element) and return the last one found. You could have just find the minimum of the last map (`return std::min_element(mymap.back().begin(), mymap.back().end(), compare`) and not bother with all the rest. (There are errors, for example you are trying to use `min` outside of the block it was declared in). Also I suspect that this is not what you want to do at all.

Comment: And as a side note, if you find yourself iterating over a map, you might be using a wrong data structure. This is not a universally applicable rule but I find it working in way too many cases.

Comment: `vec` is a confusing choice of name for an vector element. Going by type, it should rather be `map`...

Answer (score 1):

You are using min_element on each element of the map (of type std::pair<int, double>). You should have only one for instead of 2.

```
double findMin(std::vector<std::map<int, double>> const &vectorMap){
    for (auto const &vec : vectorMap){
        std::pair<int, double> min = (*std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare));
    }
    return static_cast<double>(min.second);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't call a map `vec`?

Answer (score 1):

You have confusing naming here:

```cpp
double findMin(std::vector<std::map<int, double>> const &vectorMap){
    for (auto const &vec : vectorMap){
        for (auto const &mymap : vec){
            std::pair<int, double> min = (*std::min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), compare));
        }
    }
    return static_cast<double>(min.second);
}
```

In the `for (auto const &vec : vectorMap){` line you iterate over elements of the vector, so each element of it is a map (it is obvious from its type - `std::vector<std::map<int, double>>`). So each element of the vector is a `map<int, double>`. But you call each element as a `vec` and this name may mess things for you.
Then you iterate over each map:

```cpp
for (auto const &mymap : vec)
```

and here naming is also wrong. As you iterate over map then each element of it is a `pair<int, double>` which map consists of. That's why `pair` doesn't have `begin/end` methods.
As as mentioned by [Margarit Alexandru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73590444/838444) you don't need a second loop, as your `vec` is already a `map` that can be passed to `std::min_element`. Just use correct naming)